# C# Filter to get specific Mongo Document

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "order" : "0000006"
    },

    "Catgeory" : [ 
        {
            "ID" : "62982698",

            "Data" : [ 
                {
                    "NO" : "62982698",

                    "History" : [ 
                        {
                            "Status" : null,

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "ID" : "63002696",

            "Data" : []
        }
    ],

    "Info_ID" : [ 
                "6000016405"
            ]
}
```

How to write c# mongo filter to get No:62982698 with "Info_ID" :"6000016405". No:62982698 can be part of multiple documents.So want to write filter that filters document with No 62982698  and "Info_ID" :"6000016405"

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes Adriani6 i tried below one but it was not working    var hfilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Catgeory.ID", item.ID) & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Info_ID",item.InfoID))